# Making a multiple choice button

Tags: dynamic, code-review, gui-construction

I've written the following code to create a multiple choice button that takes an arbitrary number of answer options and will assign a variable true/false depending on whether or not the correct choice is selected:

```
mchoice[question_, answers_, correct_, var_] :=
 DynamicModule[{x},
  Column[{Dynamic[var = (x == correct);], (*problem line *)
    Dynamic@
     ActionMenu[question, 
      MapThread[#1 :> (x = #2) &, {answers, Range@Length@answers}]],
    PaneSelector[
     MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Range@Length@answers, answers}], 
     Dynamic[x]]
    }]
  ]
```

The code is executed as below and gives the button:

```
Clear[avar]
mchoice["argon", {"solid", "liquid", "gas"}, 3, avar]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The correctness of the selection is stored in `avar` which I can evaluate at the end of the notebook to "grade" the quiz, if you will.  The problem is the presence of `Null` above the button.  With the code as written, I cannot seem to create a button that both updates the value of avar and doesn't print the answer.  For example, if I substitute `Dynamic[var = (x == correct)]` for the problem line, then the student will know if the chosen answer is correct.  If I use `Dynamic[var = (x == correct)];` then the result is visually correct but `avar` will not update when the student selects an answer. I *can* get the desired result by using `Dynamic[var = (x == correct);] /. {Null ->""}` but that feels like I'm cheating (yes, I'm getting the desired result, but no, I'm not using `Dynamic` correctly).

I'm interested in either of the following:

1. A better solution to my  (* problem line *)
2. Alternative methods for creating a multiple choice button.

Comment: By multiple choice you mean that one is able to change the answer given earlier?

Comment: Apropos alternative methods, isn't the standard representation for multiple choice forms in interface design radio buttons... such as `RadioButtonBar`, it would certainly make things simpler for you as well, code-wise.

Comment: `Dynamic` before `ActionMenu` is useless ?

Comment: @anon yes.  For this particular application, I am trying to simplify the type of input methods and keep the display clean.  Radio buttons with all the options take up a lot of screen real estate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DynamicWrapper[]`  :

```
 mchoice[question_, answers_, correct_, var_] := DynamicModule[{x},
  DynamicWrapper[
    Column[{
     ActionMenu[question, MapThread[#1 :> (x = #2) &, {answers, Range@Length@answers}]], 
     PaneSelector[MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Range@Length@answers, answers}], Dynamic[x]]
     }],
   var = (x == correct)]]
```

Comment: `DynamicWrapper` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but an extended comment on andre's answer.

I up-voted the answer because it's basically a good one. However, I want to point out two problems with the answer as posted.

1. The following doesn't work because y has a value when `mchoice` is called.

   ```
   y = 42; Dynamic @ y
   mchoice["argon", {"solid", "liquid", "gas"}, 3, y]
   ```
2. The following doesn't work because x is shadowed by the local x of the `DynamicModule`.

   ```
   Clear@x; Dynamic @ x
   mchoice["argon", {"solid", "liquid", "gas"}, 3, x]
   ```

I offer the following modification:

```
SetAttributes[mchoice, HoldFirst]
  mchoice[var_Symbol, question_, answers_, correct_] := 
  DynamicModule[{x$$x}, 
     DynamicWrapper[
       Column[{
         ActionMenu[
           question, 
           MapThread[#1 :> (x$$x = #2) &, {answers, Range @ Length @ answers}]], 
         PaneSelector[
           MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, 
           {Range @ Length @ answers, answers}], 
           Dynamic @ x$$x]}], 
       Unevaluated @ var = (x$$x == correct)]]
```

This isn't foolproof -- the identifier `x$$x` can't be passed in as `var` -- but it's safer than andre's version. Also, I have changed the order of the formal arguments, which is not desirable. But it is the best I can come up with.

#### Edit

The reason I changed the order of the formal arguments was to be able to use the `HoldFirst` attribute.

`Unique` could be used rather than a 'funny' local variable, but I personally find it a bit awkward. It would go like this:

```
Unique[]
```

> $3

```
Dynamic @ $3
mchoice[$3, "argon", {"solid", "liquid", "gas"}, 3]
```

---

The shadowing of global `x` by the dynamic module's local is peculiar. It appears to happen only because `x` is dynamic in the module. Consider

```
a = 42; Dynamic @ a

SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[u_] := (DynamicModule[{a}, 
  a = RandomInteger[100];
  Unevaluated@u = a];)
f[a]
```

which works; however,

```
f[u_] := (DynamicModule[{a}, 
  a = RandomInteger[100];
  Unevaluated @ u = Dynamic @ a];)
f[a]
```

fails in the same way `mchoice["argon", {"solid", "liquid", "gas"}, 3, x]` fails. It appears that wrapping the variable in question with `Dynamic` globalizes it.

Comment: Thanks for paying such close attention.  I had encountered your point 1, which I viewed as an inconvenience with an easy fix of clearing var before passing it to mchoice.  If I understand your 2nd point correctly, the variable x$$x needs to have a name that, in theory, would never be used outside of mchoice.  Is this a case for Unique[]?  I'm also interested in why the argument order change was needed as that's not clear to me.

Comment: @bobthechemist. I hope I have addressed the concerns you raise in the above comment by the edit I have made.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly fix to your code would be to put checking procedure into `ActionMenu`:

```
 MapThread[#1 :> (x = #2; var = (x == correct);) &, {answers, Range@Length@answers}]
```